# Short Circuit Evaluation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand how the following code works. I know the difference between AND and OR but this code has confused me.

```
 console.log(3 === 3 && 'cow' && console.log(34));
```

Comment: There is no short-circuiting happening in that code.

Comment: What part of it is confusing you? Does it output something you don't except? If so, what do you expect it to output instead?

Comment: result of `3 === 3` is `true` ... result of `'cow'` is `truthy` ... result of `console.log(34)` is `undefined` - what's the mystery?

Comment: why the second && why not just console.log

Comment: "why the second && why not just console.log" Well you asked it so who knows why someone did it..... Where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(3 === 3 && 'cow' && console.log(34));
```

`3 === 3` is `true`, hence goes for the next statement

```
console.log( true && 'cow' && console.log(34));
```

`'cow'` is `true` since it's a non empty string literal, hence the next statement

```
console.log( true && true && console.log(34));
```

`console.log(34)` executes function, prints `34`, returns `undefined`

```
console.log( true && true && undefined);
```

prints `undefined`

so finally in the console you'll have

```
34 
undefined
```

Comment: why the second && why not just console.log

Comment: Because statements are evaluated from left to right

Answer (score 0):

The first two Boolean results, `3 === 3` and `'cow'`, both evaluate to true. That means the final expression also needs to be evaluated to see if the entire expression is true or false.

Evaluating `console.log(34)` has the side effect of printing `34` to the console, so that line appears first.

`console.log(34)` has no return type, so the result of its evaluation is `undefined`. The result of anding any truthy value with `undefined` is also `undefined`, so the entire expression `3 === 3 && 'cow' && console.log(34)` evaluates to `undefined`. This is printed to the console on the line after `34`.